# It is Showing context is undefined

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

This dart project it is showing an error **that context is undefined** and when i sent it as an argument it is showing error i am new to flutter and my mentor wrote the same(as i have seen)
i am facing this problem

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Category_item extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  Category_item(this.title, this.color);
  void selectCategory() {
    Navigator.of(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: selectCategory,
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), //wave ripple waves
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              color.withOpacity(0.7),
              color,
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 void selectCategory() {
    Navigator.of(context);
  }
```

this function is outside the build.
try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Category_item extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  Category_item(this.title, this.color);
  void selectCategory() {
    Navigator.of(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: selectCategory,
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), //wave ripple waves
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              color.withOpacity(0.7),
              color,
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
selectCategory(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to have an input for the context in order for it to know what the context is.

```
void selectCategory(BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.of(context);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
```